# Hide external Iframe Criteo async tag when passback empty

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, iframe, external, criteo

Hope someone can help us. We need to hide an external iframe without passback that the async Criteo tag creates, (resulting in a white empty space) when no banner is loaded. Any idea?

This is the tag:

```
    <div id="one" margin="0px">
    <script>
    var cto_zoneid_desktop = "xxxxxx";
    var cto_zoneid_mobile = "xxxxxx";
     var cto_lim_w = 700,cto_lim_h = 200,cto_zoneid_selected = cto_zoneid_desktop;
    if( window.screen.width<window.cto_lim_w || window.screen.height<window.cto_lim_h){cto_zoneid_selected = cto_zoneid_mobile;}
    var crt_curl = '#CLICK_URL_UNESC#';
    (function(w,d,s,c,z,u){var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),l = '&loc=' + encodeURIComponent(w.location), r = d.referrer ? '&referer=' + encodeURIComponent(d.referrer) : '', g = u.substring(0,4) == 'http' ? '&ct0='+encodeURIComponent(u) : '', cb="&cb="+Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999) ;j.async='true';j.src=(("https:"==location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+
    '//cas.criteo.com/delivery/ajs.php?zoneid='+z+'&containerid='+c+g+l+r+cb).substring(0,2000);f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','one',cto_zoneid_selected,crt_curl);
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to hide the iframe from Criteo in case of no banner. Put in the passback the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.frameElement.style.display = "none";
    </script>
```

It works. Hope it may help someone.